# Ubuntu freezes on building project

Tags: gcc, freeze, ubuntu-20.04

I'm using gcc 10.0.3. and СMake. When I building project, Ubuntu 20.04 freezes and I can't do anything, so I have to wait until it coming to life (but it is too long) or press power button to hard reboot it. I try to used build flag -j 4 (default it is 6), reduce processor speed to 1.5 - 2 GHz (by using gnome extensions).
Maybe computer starts trotting, but extension show that temperature about 60 - 65 degrees, so I don't think it is.

I have 16 gb RAM, intel core i7 (11 generations, 4 physical cores)

Comment: I also have this issue, but I am already using an nVidia driver.

Answer (score 0):

I switched from the default XOrg to an Nvidia native video driver.  Seems to have resolved my Ubuntu UI freezing issue.
Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers (tab at top) -> choose "Using NVIDIA driver (open kernel) ... tested" -> follow bios update instructions.